# Adding custom option in kde settings

Tags: kde, lfs

I recently made a Linux From Scratch and installed KDE4. Now I want to add an option named "about" in the KDE settings, which will display info about my LFS.
 My question is **"Is it possible?"** If yes then how?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because KDE4 was deprecated in 2014.